# How can I access the certain value more easily in the child component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am coming from the React background so I don't really know much about Vue.
The thing is I need to fix some stuff in a Vue project.

In the Parent component.

```
import NumberField from '../fields/NumberField.vue'; //Child component

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Questionnaire',
  components: {
    MultipleChoiceField,
    NumberField,
    ....
  },
});

const fieldType = computed<string>(() => {
  questionTitleAttribute();
  switch (currentQuestion.value.type) {
    case 'multiple_choice':
      return 'MultipleChoiceField';
    case 'number':
      return 'NumberField';
    default:
      console.error('Unidentified field type');
      return '';
  }
});

<div>
    <component
        id="current"
        :is="fieldType"
        :question="currentQuestion"
        :answer="currentAnswer"
        :show-insights="showInsights"
        :additions="additions"
        :set-question="setQuestion"
     />
</div>
```

As you can see it is choosing from multiple field and use the appropriate one. But the thing is currently  you can see the statement `:question="currentQuestion"`

What I want to do is I want to access the `currentQuestion.validation` in the child component. But It is kind of complicated when I try to `console.log` in the child component. Is there better way to get the value directly?

Here is `child component`

```
const props = withDefaults(
  defineProps<{
    question: QuestionnaireField;
    answer?: QuestionnaireNumberAnswer | undefined;
    additions: PrefilledAdditionalParameters;
  }>(),
  { answer: undefined }
);

    const emit = defineEmits(['allowContinue', 'editAnswer']);
    
    const { additions, answer, question } = toRefs(props);
    
    console.log('-----');
    console.log(question);
    console.log('-----');
```

Here is the nested object which I need to access the validations. This is the image of question log [image]

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. The way Vue reactive objects are represented in console doesn't affect the way you work with them

Comment: @EstusFlask I want to get the validations but its nested too deeply. Normally I should be able to get by `questions.validations` but not in this case

Comment: What are these validations? Nested too deeply - like what? What does prevent you from accessing them? It's an object. Can be accessed the same way as any other object in JS, as long as this doesn't destroy the reactivity. The question lacks clear problem statement.

Comment: Here is the object passed from parent to child


 `question = {
  validations : {
    maxValue: 12,
    ...
  }
}`

As you can see in the picture I can't access the validations element easily just by 
`questions.validations.maxvalue`

Comment: @EstusFlask I don't say that it is preventing me from accessing the values. What I mean is that I can't access it in the normal way like I mention in the above comment. Now I need to write some thing like this to get the value

`question._object.question.validations.max_value`

Comment: I don't see this. See above, "The way Vue reactive objects are represented in console doesn't affect the way you work with them". No, you don't need anything like like `question._object...`. It's a ref and should be `unref(question).validations.max_value`, or even better `props.question....` - a ref doesn't serve a good purpose here and doesn't make it shorter. If it's unavailable this means that it's really isn't at this moment of time

Comment: @EstusFlask Yep Now I can access the value more easily now using `unref`. Why this not work `question.validations.max_value`

Comment: Because `question` is ref object, i.e. an object with the only `value` public property, which can be anything. It's similar to React refs and serves similar purposes